# What can I use as the generic term for "a function that is composed with another"?

Tags: functions, terminology, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose I am talking about the composition $g \circ f$ (or more generally $f_n \circ \cdots \circ f_1$). Is there a generic term for the functions $f$ and $g$ (the functions $f_i$)?

"Compositand"?